# How can I protect my idea outside the US?

Tags: patentability, mobile

I have an idea on my mind related to a feature on a mobile that can help someone in their life.

I am outside of the USA. How can I protect my idea and where can I register it so later no mobile company or other people can take it?

Answer (score 0):

On your first point, you would typically apply for a patent in your home country first. Within the first year, you would then apply in other countries (such as the US) via Convention applications or alternatively via a PCT application. In this manner, you can protect your invention in whatever countries you deem worthwhile.

You should likely discuss this with a patent attorney in your country. Alternatively, your university may have a IP commercialisation arm which could help.

Your second and third points [edit: that have been edited out of the question as of topic] are off topic for this site (since we only deal with patents). [Startups](https://startups.stackexchange.com/) might be a good place to ask though.

Comment: After one year or within one year?

Comment: @EricShain nice catch, should be within the first year

Comment: @Maca I edited your answer, if you don't like it, that's your prob... *I mean then I'm sorry, edit it again* ;)

Comment: @DonQuiKong Fine by me!